# partial specialisation and nested templates

Tags: c++, templates

I try to do partial specialisation for a template function where the specialized type `T` might also be a class template. However the following Code does not work.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <class T>
constexpr T neutral();

template <>
constexpr int neutral() { return 0; } // Okay. This is how partial specialisation works.

template <class U>
constexpr std::vector<U> neutral() { return std::vector<U>{ neutral<U>() }; }

int main()
{
    const auto n{ neutral<std::vector<int>>() }; // error
}


main.cpp:16:19: error: call to 'neutral' is ambiguous
    const auto n{ neutral<std::vector<int>>() }; // error
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:5:13: note: candidate function [with T = std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >]
constexpr T neutral();
            ^
main.cpp:11:26: note: candidate function [with U = std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >]
constexpr std::vector<U> neutral() { return std::vector<U>{ neutral<U>() }; } //error
                         ^
```

*My design goal is as follows: I provide an algorithm that can take any type that any programmer wants to use as long as he defines what the so called `natural<T>()` of his type `T` is. (However my actual code looks differently. This is a minimalistic example I tried to extract.)*

How can it be implemented correctly?

I first thought, it must be something like

```cpp
template <>
template <class U>
constexpr std::vector<U> neutral<std::vector<U>>() { return std::vector<U>{ neutral<U>() }; } //error
```

But this also ends up in errors:

```
main.cpp:11:26: error: function template partial specialization is not allowed
constexpr std::vector<U> neutral<std::vector<U>>() { return std::vector<U>{ neutral<U>() }; } //error
                         ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

**EDIT:**
The context I want to use it is like this...

I have some class `class Z7` which is representing a [(math.) ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)). I want to use something like the `neutral` in the example for the zero and the one element of the ring. Then there is a class

```cpp
template <class _Ring>
class polynomial;
```

which will represent polynoms over the ring `_Ring`, e.g., `2x^5 + x^3 + 4x + 1`. Therefore, `polynomial<_Ring>` will also be a ring whenever `_Ring` has been a ring. Thus I want to define a template specialisation for a zero and a one for `polynomial<_Ring>` by using the zero and one of type `_Ring`.

Comment: `error: function template partial specialization is not allowed` pretty much speaks for itself. You can partially specialize classes, but not functions. (Your first specialization of `neutral` is a *full* specialization (the comment on it is wrong), those are allowed.) A possible workaround is to make your function a class member, and specialize that class.

Comment: Unrelated, `std::vector<U>{ neutral<U>() }` seems wierd. Why would a neutral vector always contain exactly 1 element?

Comment: @MooingDuck It contains such an element only because I needed to crete a minimal example from the original code.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Can you provide a minimal example for doing so with class template specialisation. I tried, but it also ended up in some "no üpartial specialisation for function template"

Comment: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/xtHMSW

Comment: Thanks @HolyBlackCat ! I'll try to patch this in my original problem. If I'll succeed I may post it as answer if no one did before.

Answer (score 1):

Functions need a difference in their parameters to have different definitions, classes/structs can be specialized without such a constraint, perhaps what you're looking for is closer to...

```
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
struct neutral;

template <typename T>
struct neutral {
    static constexpr int get() { return 0; } 
};

template <typename T>
struct neutral<std::vector<T>> {
    static constexpr std::vector<T> get() { return std::vector<T>(); } 
};

int main()
{
    const auto n{ neutral<std::vector<int>>::get() };
    const auto m{ neutral<float>::get() };
}
```